# Attach imported class to namespace

Tags: typescript, class, plugins, leaflet, type-declaration

I have a leaflet plugin I'm writing that I want to attach to the global `L` object.  It attaches an object `MyPlugin` to the global `L`, and various properties and methods are available on `L.MyPlugin`.  One of those properties is actually a class, called `SpecialLayer`.  I am writing my type declaration file for the plugin, and I'm not sure how to include that.

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import { ConfigOptions } from './types';
import SpecialLayer from './SpecialLayer';

declare module 'leaflet' {
    export namespace MyPlugin {
        function someFunction(something: string): string;

        function anotherFunction(userConfig: Partial<ConfigOptions>): ConfigOptions;

        const _config: ConfigOptions;

        const _cache: {};
    }
}
```

I don't know how to attach a class among these functions and consts, which becomes the `typeof SpecialLayer`.  Here are a few things I've tried that don't work.  Within the `export namespace MyPlugin` block:

```
    class SpecialLayer = SpecialLayer; // error: '{' expected.

    class SpecialLayer {} // doesn't bring type definitions from SpecialLayer into namespace?
```

How do I bring `SpecialLayer` into the L.MyPlugin namespace, while reusing all the existing typescript definitions from the externally defined `SpecialLayer` class?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { foo as _foo } from "./foo";

export namespace abc {
   export let foo=_foo;
   export type foo=_foo;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 